# why don't show the textbox value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, dataset

I've written this value to show the textbox5 value but it is not showing the value of this textbox.

Where Is the problem i can not find it, it shows only blank.

**Design Code:**

```
<p class="style1"> Formulated : <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"     
AutoPostBack="True" ReadOnly="True" OnTextChanged="txt4_TextChanged" 
BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black">
</asp:TextBox> 
</p> <p class="style1"> Peice : <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"   
AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="Black" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void txt4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text)) 
        {
            TextBox5.Text = ((Convert.ToDouble(TextBox4.Text)) * 8).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if `TextBox4.Text` can be parsed to double or not.

Comment: could you please show us the design code?

Comment: @RohitVats: if it can not be parsed then runtime error will be thrown as he is using the `Convert.ToDouble()` IMO

Comment: i have tried also in Toint32 but same situation..

Comment: there is no problem with the code posted, i think the event is not properly attached to textbox, please share the textbox4 and textbox5 design code.

Comment: <p class="style1">
        Formulated :
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ReadOnly="True" OnTextChanged="txt4_TextChanged"
            BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p class="style1">
        Peice : 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="Black" 
            ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: In simple words i want to say - `Attach a debugger and see values`. Or post some relevant reproducing the issue.

Comment: @user3079335: you can use javascript to invoke serverside events check my edited answer with section `Solution`

Answer (score 0):

I Think `TextBox` as a Web server control does not raise an event each time the user enters a keystroke, it will be fired only once if the user leaves the control.

So `TextChanged` Event fires when you `leave` the control.

**Solution :**
so you need to handle Key Events using Javascript to invoke serverside code for each key press

**Try This:** the following design code helps you to run event for each key press.

**Design Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
 function RefreshPage() {
    __doPostBack('<%= TextBox4.ClientID %>', '');
};

</script>
<p class="style1"> Formulated : <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4"      
onkeyup="RefreshPage();" runat="server"     
AutoPostBack="True" ReadOnly="True" OnTextChanged="txt4_TextChanged" 
BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black">
</asp:TextBox> 
</p> <p class="style1"> Peice : <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"   
AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="Black" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have TextBoox4 as "ReadOnly=True" so I assume you set the value in the Textbox4 in your code behind but doing that won't fire the OnTextChanged event. It will fire OnTextChanged event only when you type in text and then leave the control as Sudhakar says.

I tried your code by removing the ReadOnly attribute from TextBox4 and typing a number in it and it fires the txt4_TextChanged event on leaving the control and sets the value in TextBox5.